# Уведомления о новых пользователях в Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

День добрый! Подскажите пожалуйста, когда новый пользователь запускает бота как сделать так, чтобы мне приходило уведомление типа:пользователь с никнеймом подключился к боту? Желательно без sql, я в этом пока не шарю.

Comment: Напишите что-то в духе - `bot.send_message(12345678, f'Пользователь {message.from_user.username} подключился к боту')` где `12345678` - ваш chat_id. Но такой вариант будет срабатывать всегда при нажатии `/start`, поэтому значение `chat_id` юзеров все равно нужно где-то хранить. Можно хранить и в списках/словарях/кортежах... но при перезапуске бота - все данные потеряются. Или еще как вариант - записывать chat_id в обычный текстовый файл, и уже сверять, есть ли такой

Comment: Но лучше выбрать наиболее подходящий вариант для этой задачи - подучить sql, и подключить БД sqlite, тем более это не так сложно, как кажется:) Удачи.

Comment: Спасибо, меня это устроит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/batman22827/AlertTelegram

- Сделано на sqlite довольно простой лабе

Comment: Спасибо, пригодится позже, я пока с sql не разбирался

Comment: Это еще проще, чем обычный sql, хранить данные в txt файле непрактично.